90's series about time travelling
I'm born in the 1990's. When I was kid, don't remember how old I was, I remember an American series about time traveling being shown in the late 90's maybe beginning of 2000's. 
The main character was a teenager boy who might have lost his mom. Together with some friends he traveled to other worlds/universes. 
I remember one episode with people looking like dolls. There was a woman in that episode that tried to cry but couldn't and then she draw tears on her cheek. Another episode with traveling to another world with huge furniture, so the people seemed quite small. There was also an episode where they traveled back in time and the main character saw his parents. 
I remember the TV show being showed in foreign channels as well, so I guess it was quite popular at that time. Please help me find this series

We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. What time period was it showing?  Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions

Do you remember how they travel?

Unfortunately, no. But I remember that they went back to present in every episode

Is it animated or live-action?

it was live-action

NO time travelling but universes traveling. 
Sliders A young genius his, professor and random people try to travel to "their" earth. The young guy had only his mom. 
At the end of every episode they "jumped" to new earth thinking it was the one. 

I agree that this seems like a good match, but I don't remember any of the samples the OP describes from Sliders episodes.  (It has been a while, so maybe I've just forgotten...)

I'm gonna take a look at Sliders, might be that one. Thanks :)
